# Google APIs Client Library for JS 'Access Not Configured' error

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-client

I am trying to get to work a sample described here (with Calendar API):

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.hu/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html

The code itself runs properly, but I always get an error message (pasted from JSON):

> "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

Of course I have enabled the Calendar API for my project, I have set the api and the client keys too.

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi nimesulide. Any luck with this error. I am stuck with the same.

Answer (score 0):

"Access not configured" error is thrown when the project is not configured to access THIS API.
Can you check whether Calendar API is enabled to this project(which you are getting error)?

Also, this error can happen due to the below reasons:

1. The project which is throwing error has been blocked due to abuse.
2. The project has been marked for deletion.

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/errors#FORBIDDEN) for documentation on the standard error messages.

Comment: Actually the Calendar API is enabled, but the error still says that it's not.

Comment: Please check on the other two scenarios mentioned above?

Comment: None of these, and as I said in my question. The JSON received says: "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."

Comment: Now I am confused. :) In the Dev Console I edited the allowed referers list to any referer allowed, and now I get an error message that says 404 (not found) error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems solved. As it seems, the sample source code was wrong at some points. You should better use google's own sample codes to try out APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Android using GoogleAuthUtil to get the token. Eventually I realised that I was compiling on a different machine with a different SHA1 certificate.

To fix it I added another Android ClientID in the google developers console and also needed to call GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken